# How do I make Xcode 4 run my Pre-Actions?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I can't seem to get Xcode 4 to reliably execute my pre-actions.  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding.  It doesn't seem to do it consistently.  Is it even trying?  I can't tell.  I've put some echos in it (it's a bash script) and nothing is happening.  This all worked in Xcode 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that pre-actions do not pick up env variables. They are primarily meant to load or notify that the build is starting. If it worked in Xcode 3, you may want to use it more as a build script than a pre-action.

Comment: Also, make sure the pre-action is connected to the scheme you are currently building under, the UI makes it pretty easy to miss a change in scheme and I have noticed mine changes sometimes when I re-open a project.

Comment: Thanks.  So I ended up making a shell script external to the project and ran that manually prior to compilation.  That worked for my project, though a bit less than ideal.  Thanks again.

Comment: I just read that this was fixed in 4.1, but have not tested it yet.

Comment: As of 4.6.3 my Archive pre-action script is simply not executed even when schemes match.

Answer (score 17):

Note that your pre-build actions are not executed in your project's source directory. They are executed somewhere in `Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/`.

If you want to play with files in your project's source directory before compilation, you need to prepend it with `${PROJECT_DIR}/`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a "Run Script" to your build phases, and then drag it's position above the compile sources build phase.

I don't understand the purpose of a "pre-action" yet, doesn't seem to even get executed. However in my case I just needed a script to execute before my sources were compiled.

Comment: Pre-build actions are done before any target begins to build. Run Scripts happen when a specific target is building. This is useful for scenarios where your build dependencies make it impossible for you to run your script early enough.

Comment: I believe this does not have the effect you expect.  Looking at the build log, the plist file is processed before the Run Script even if you move it above everything.  So, if your modifying the plist from your script (e.g., bumping the build number) it would happen after the plist has been copied.

Comment: What if you need to send your dependency library some variables to build upon like a flag or something  .... using a run script cannot be executed before the target dependencies

Comment: Here's an example: Xcode only performs build steps it considers necessary. If your script phase modifies a file that was unmodified when the build was started, Xcode won't re-build it as the decision whether to build that file or not was made before the build started and this decision is not updated. In that case only building again will make Xcode see that change. But if the pre-action modified a file, then Xcode will see it is modified when it starts the build.